# Combining RIGHT JOIN with COUNT

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to get a list of the number of entries in the `changes_cc` table by each user. Not all users have made entries into it, however for some reason it's returning "1" for each user that has 0 entries. I'm assuming that it's because it's counting the entries in the `JOIN`ed table. How can I make it so that it is "0" instead?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num, users.id, realname, username
            FROM changes_cc
            RIGHT JOIN users
                ON changes_cc.user_id = users.id
            GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Try using an inner join instead

Comment: @JohnConde that would only show the users that have entries.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. They're all right. I'll have to use "eenie meenie miney moe" to decide who to accept ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work -- count a specific field in the changes_cc table vs counting *:

```
SELECT u.id, realname, username, COUNT(c.id) as num
FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN changes_cc c 
        ON u.user_id = c.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

I prefer reading a `LEFT JOIN` over a `RIGHT JOIN`, but they are both `OUTER JOINs` and work the same.

Comment: I used same query as you suggested, But This Query return only matched data from both table.

Actually, I want all data from user table and count of changes, If some user has no count than also i want that record.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `COUNT(*)` (*counts the record including null values*) because it will normally give atleast 1 since it returns all records from the right table. If you specify the column name to be counted, it will gove you the result you want because `COUNT` only counts for *NON_NULL* value.

```
SELECT  COUNT(changes_cc.user_id) as num, 
        users.id, 
        realname, 
        username
FROM    changes_cc
        RIGHT JOIN users
            ON changes_cc.user_id = users.id
GROUP   BY users.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `count(*)`, use `count(changes_cc.user_id)`.

The problem is that you are counting rows (with the `*`) rather than counting the non-NULL values in the "right-joined" table.