# Counting with outer joins only returns data from which count is not zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, outer-join

Say I have two tables: `user` and `diary`.

```
select count(id)
from user
where is_tester is false
```

Here the primary keys are always called `id`. This query above gives me about 270000, which means I have about 270000 users. Now I'd like to know how many diaries each user has. So I went:

```
select u.id as user_id, u.dm_type, count(d.id) as bg_count
from diary as d
right join (
    select id, dm_type
    from user
    where is_tester is false
) as u
on d.user_id = u.id
where d.glucose_value > 0
group by u.id, u.dm_type
```

Each user can have only one kind of `dm_type`. I am expecting that it would tell me how many diaries each user has, and if one doesn't have any diary, it would give me an NA or 0 since I used `right join`. However, the returned table has only about 75000 rows and every users in that table have at least one diary. That's not what I want. Why does it happen and how should I do it correctly?

I've referred to [Combining RIGHT JOIN with COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561811/combining-right-join-with-count), and count one specific field according to the suggestion from the accepted answer.

---

Edits according to the comments:

`user`:

```
| id | dm_type | is_tester |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | 1       | False     |
| 2  | 1       | False     |
| 3  | 2       | False     |
| 4  | no      | False     |
| 5  | 2       | True      |
```

`diary`:

```
| id | user_id | glucose_value |
|----|---------|---------------|
| 1  | 1       | -2            |
| 2  | 1       | 80            |
| 3  | 2       | 78            |
| 4  | 2       | 100           |
| 5  | 4       | 83            |
| 6  | 5       | 90            |
```

Expected result:

```
| user_id | dm_type | bg_count |
|---------|---------|----------|
| 1       | 1       | 1        |
| 2       | 1       | 2        |
| 3       | 2       | 0        |
| 4       | no      | 1        |
```

Comment: Please share table structure an d desired output

Comment: @user2864740 `right outer join` gives me exactly the same result. BTW it seems that you misunderstood my desired output. I _don't_ want `HAVING COUNT(d.id) > 0` or `INNER JOIN` because I _do_ need those rows of `COUNT(d.id)` is 0.

Comment: @user2864740 Excuse me but I don't get what you're trying to say... I _did_ `right join`, didn't I? And I tried `right out join` according to your comment above. So what wrong with it?

Comment: @ytu, could you please try below answer, i hope it will solve your issue

Comment: @codeLover Please see my edits in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `where` clause.  It is filtering out unmatched diaries from the outer join.

When you are approaching this type of problem, I strongly recommend `left join` over `right join`.  It means "keep all the rows in the first table even if nothing matches in the second".  This is usually easier to follow than "keep all the rows in whatever table is at the end of the from clause but I haven't seen yet".

The next rule is that conditions on the *first* table go in the `where` clause because they really filter rows.  Conditions on the second table go in the `on` clause.  They don't filter rows but are used for matching.

So, you can phrase your query as:

```
select u.id as user_id, u.dm_type, count(d.id) as bg_count
from user u left join
     diary d
     on d.user_id = u.id and d.glucose_value > 0
where u.is_tester is false
group by u.id, u.dm_type;
```

No subquery is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try with left join, it will give you all user whether it has diary count or not
If any user has no diary then it will give you null

```
select u.id as user_id, u.dm_type, count(d.id) as bg_count from
(select id, dm_type from user where is_tester is false)u
left join diary d on d.user_id = u.id and d.glucose_value > 0
group by u.id, u.dm_type
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is causing `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "d"`. It should probably be `left join diary as d on d.user_id = u.id`. But it still gives me the same table even after I revise your answer accordingly.

Comment: edited the answer ..now check I missed the alias for dairy table and also you need to apply condition d.glucose_value > 0 in on clause. If you apply it where clause then it will filter out the result. I hope now it will help u